# How to validate a child object attributes when self-reference association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a one model 'Task' and have two entities - 'tasks' and 'subtasks' with self-reference association.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :subtasks, class_name: 'Task', foreign_key: 'parent_id', dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to  :parent, class_name: 'Task'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subtasks, allow_destroy: true
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }
  validates :priority, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }, length: { is: 1 }
  validates_associated :subtasks
end
```

And i use one controller - TasksController.

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :run, :complete]
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_task

  def run
    @task.run!
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def complete
    @task.complete!
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @task = Task.create(task_params)
    if @task.errors.empty?
      redirect_to tasks_path, notice: "Task created!"
    else
      render 'new', notice: "Invalid input!"
    end
  end

  def update
    @task.update_attributes(task_params)
    if @task.errors.empty? || :subtasks_attributes?
      redirect_to @task
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @task.destroy
    if @task.parent_id?
      redirect_to @task.parent
    else
      redirect_to tasks_path
    end
  end

  private

    def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:title, :description, :scheduled, :deadline, :priority, :project, subtasks_attributes: [:title, :priority])
    end

    def find_task
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    end

    def invalid_task
      redirect_to tasks_path, notice: "Invalid task!"
    end

end
```

I wanna create subtasks on task show page:

```
  - @task.subtasks.each do |subtask|
    - if subtask.in_work?
      => link_to 'Complete', complete_task_path(subtask), method: :put
    - else
      => link_to 'Run', run_task_path(subtask), method: :put
      => subtask.title
      => link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(subtask)
      = link_to 'Delete', [subtask], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
  = simple_form_for @task do |t|
    = t.simple_fields_for :subtasks, @task.subtasks.build do |f|
      .form-inputs
        = f.input :title
        = f.hidden_field :priority, value: @task.priority
      .form-actions
        = f.button  :submit, "Add a subtask"
```

Now on the task show page i can create a subtask with valid attributes and can't create a subtask with invalid attributes, but i do not get validation message. 
How can i fix it? 
Ty and sorry for my English.

**PS:**
i don't know why, but errors exist inside controller and doesn't exist inside view

```
@project.update_attributes(project_params)
puts @project.errors.full_messages
if @project.errors.empty? || :tasks_attributes?
  redirect_to @project
  puts @project.errors.full_messages

   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
Tasks title can't be blank
Tasks title is too short (minimum is 3 characters)
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/projects/3
Tasks title can't be blank
Tasks title is too short (minimum is 3 characters)
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add the errors messages to the view too:

```
= simple_form_for @task do |t|
= t.simple_fields_for :subtasks, @task.subtasks.build do |f|
   #error message added here
   - if @task.subtasks.errors.any?
     %ul.errors
       - @task.subtasks.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
       %li= msg
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :title
    = f.hidden_field :priority, value: @task.priority
  .form-actions
    = f.button  :submit, "Add a subtask"
```

**EDIT**

You have a _form partial in you application, change that code to this

```
= simple_form_for @task do |f|
- if @task.errors.any?
 ul.errors
   - @task.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
    => msg

= f.input :title
= f.input :description
= f.input :scheduled
= f.input :deadline
= f.input :priority, collection: [["None", 0], ["High", 3], ["Medium", 2], ["Low", 1]], selected: ["None"]
= f.button :submit
```

Comment: Hm, i got 
`undefined method "errors" for #<Task::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f7a723ceb48>`

Comment: does the Subtask model has `belongs_to :task` in it?

Comment: I have only one model - 'Task':
`has_many    :subtasks, class_name: 'Task', foreign_key: 'parent_id', dependent: :destroy` 
  `belongs_to  :parent, class_name: 'Task'`

Comment: yep, i have it in layout: `
            - flash.each do |name, msg|
              = content_tag :div, msg, class: "alert alert-info"
          = yield`
damn, can't do code string by string. If it help full code is here https://github.com/odinsy/taskmanager/tree/tasks

Comment: that is for showing only the flash messages, the code in the answer is for showing the validation error messages

Comment: I added it, but it does'nt work, don't get validation errors